# If found duplicates in array, have to add the index with key by pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have set of items in array. There are multiple objects are there in each item.

If we have found duplicated items based on particular object, have to add index with that key object

for Ex:

```
var values = [
    { name: 'someName' },
    { name: 'someName' },
    { name: 'some' },
    { name: 'some' },
    { name: 'single' }
];
```

It would come as

```
var values = [
        { name: 'someName' },
        { name: 'someName1' },
        { name: 'some' },
        { name: 'some1' },
        { name: 'single' }
    ];
```

How can i write a logic for this in pure javascript(No jQuery)

https://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/kr88up0m/1/

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I have added in jsfiddle but couldn't able to get logic

Comment: Added jsfiddle in a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `thisArgs` of [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as a temporary object for keeping the count.

```js
var values = [{ name: 'someName' }, { name: 'someName' }, { name: 'some' }, { name: 'some' }, { name: 'single' }];

values.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]) {
        this[a.name] = { count: 0 };
        return;
    }
    a.name += ++this[a.name].count;
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(values, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The question and the example are not very inline.

> If we have found duplicated items based on particular object, have to add index with that key object

From the above sentence what i understand is, if we find a duplicate, either one of the followings shall be done. Since it's also unclear what happens if multiple duplicates exist, the code will handle all existing duplicates.

**1.** The first one's index value will be added to the duplicate object's name property value.

```js
var values = [
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'some'     },
              { name: 'some'     },
              { name: 'single'   },
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'some'     }
             ],
     redIx = values.reduce((p,c,i) => { !!p[c.name] ? p[c.name].push(i) : (p[c.name] = [], p[c.name].push(i))
                                        return p
                                      },{});console.log(redIx)
Object.keys(redIx).forEach( e => redIx[e].forEach((i,j) => j>0 && (values[i].name += redIx[e][0])));
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

**2.** The duplicate's own index value will be added to it's name property value.

```js
var values = [
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'some'     },
              { name: 'some'     },
              { name: 'single'   },
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'some'     }
             ],
      redIx = values.reduce((p,c,i) => { !!p[c.name] ? p[c.name].push(i) : p[c.name] = [];
                                         return p
                                       },{});
Object.keys(redIx).forEach( e => redIx[e].forEach(i => values[i].name += i));
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

**3.** "1" character will be added to the duplicate object's name property value like shown in the example.

```js
var values = [
           { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'some'     },
              { name: 'some'     },
              { name: 'single'   },
              { name: 'someName' },
              { name: 'some'     }
             ],
     redIx = values.reduce((p,c,i) => { !!p[c.name] ? p[c.name].push(i) : p[c.name] = [];
                                        return p
                                      },{});
Object.keys(redIx).forEach( e => redIx[e].forEach(i => values[i].name += "1"));
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```